Keep getting error when trying to create a Web PubSub Service in azure
I am currently trying to set up a WebPub Service in azure to host the server side of my socket.io application and when I proceed to review and create the resource I get this error: 
I tried to create a signalR resource in azure but I keep getting the same error message


Resource provider(s): Microsoft. SignalRService is not registered for subscription SW LLC SUBSCRIPTION, and you don't have permissions to register a resource provider for subscription SW LLC SUBSCRIPTION.

Initially, I also encountered the same error in my environment when I tried to create the Web PubSub for Socket.IO.
Error:

According to this MS-Document, the above error occurs when you haven't registered your resource with your subscription.
Portal:
Portal-> < Your-Subscription> -> Resource providers -> search Microsoft. SignalRService -> Register.

After registering the resource with the subscription, the error was fixed in my environment.
Portal:

You can also register the resource through the CLI.
Command:
az provider register --namespace Microsoft.SignalRService

Reference:

Resource providers and resource types - Azure Resource Manager | Microsoft Learn
Permissions to perform /register/action operations on the resource provider - Microsoft Q&A

